# Pluck items from JSON array into new variables based on a property value in each item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Based on this JSON array below I need to split it into separate JSON arrays based on the `category` property on each item.

So all items with the category property set to `person` will be plucked out and into a new variable holding a new JSON array with just the `category` items.

I then need to do this for each category found using JavaScript or jQuery.

The sample data below has 3 different category values:

- person
- address
- it

code:

```
var mock_data_types =  [ 
    {
        "type":"first_name",
        "name":"First Name1",
        "description": "Random generated First Name",
        "example":"Jason",
        "category":"person"
    },
    {
        "type": "last_name",
        "name": "Last Name2",
        "description": "Random generated Last Name",
        "example": "Davis",
        "category": "address"
    },
    {
        "type": "domain",
        "name": "Domain Name3",
        "description": "Random generated WWW Domain Name",
        "example": "google.com",
        "category": "it"
    },
    {
        "type": "Gender",
        "name": "Gender4",
        "description": "Random generated Gender Type",
        "example": "Female",
        "category": "person"
    },
    {
        "type": "first_name",
        "name": "First Name5",
        "description": "Random generated First Name",
        "example": "Jason",
        "category": "person"
    },
    {
        "type": "last_name",
        "name": "Last Name6",
        "description": "Random generated Last Name",
        "example": "Davis",
        "category": "address"
    },
    {
        "type": "domain",
        "name": "Domain Name7",
        "description": "Random generated WWW Domain Name",
        "example": "google.com",
        "category": "person"
    },
    {
        "type": "Gender",
        "name": "Gender8",
        "description": "Random generated Gender Type",
        "example": "Female",
        "category": "address"
    },
    {
        "type": "first_name",
        "name": "First Name9",
        "description": "Random generated First Name",
        "example": "Jason",
        "category": "it"
    },
    {
        "type": "last_name",
        "name": "Last Name10",
        "description": "Random generated Last Name",
        "example": "Davis",
        "category": "person"
    },
    {
        "type": "domain",
        "name": "Domain Name11",
        "description": "Random generated WWW Domain Name",
        "example": "google.com",
        "category": "it"
    },
    {
        "type": "Gender",
        "name": "Gender12",
        "description": "Random generated Gender Type",
        "example": "Female",
        "category": "person"
    },
    {
        "type": "first_name",
        "name": "First Name13",
        "description": "Random generated First Name",
        "example": "Jason",
        "category": "address"
    },
    {
        "type": "last_name",
        "name": "Last Name14",
        "description": "Random generated Last Name",
        "example": "Davis",
        "category": "person"
    },
    {
        "type": "domain",
        "name": "Domain Name15",
        "description": "Random generated WWW Domain Name",
        "example": "google.com",
        "category": "it"
    },
    {
        "type": "Gender",
        "name": "Gender16",
        "description": "Random generated Gender Type",
        "example": "Female",
        "category": "person"
    },
];
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2):

this is a simple javascript solution without using any libraries

```
var dt = {};
for(var a=0;a<mock_data_types.length;a++) {
    if(dt[mock_data_types[a].category]){
        dt[mock_data_types[a].category].push(mock_data_types[a])
    }else{
        dt[mock_data_types[a].category] = [mock_data_types[a]];
    }

}
```

Comment: That's fine for the "person" category but what about *"I then need to do this for each category found"*?

Comment: Avoid using `for...in` to iterate over an array. Consider `for...of` or `.forEach`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty easy job for [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
var mock_data_types =  [{"type":"first_name","name":"First Name1","description":"Random generated First Name","example":"Jason","category":"person"},{"type":"last_name","name":"Last Name2","description":"Random generated Last Name","example":"Davis","category":"address"},{"type":"domain","name":"Domain Name3","description":"Random generated WWW Domain Name","example":"google.com","category":"it"},{"type":"Gender","name":"Gender4","description":"Random generated Gender Type","example":"Female","category":"person"},{"type":"first_name","name":"First Name5","description":"Random generated First Name","example":"Jason","category":"person"},{"type":"last_name","name":"Last Name6","description":"Random generated Last Name","example":"Davis","category":"address"},{"type":"domain","name":"Domain Name7","description":"Random generated WWW Domain Name","example":"google.com","category":"person"},{"type":"Gender","name":"Gender8","description":"Random generated Gender Type","example":"Female","category":"address"},{"type":"first_name","name":"First Name9","description":"Random generated First Name","example":"Jason","category":"it"},{"type":"last_name","name":"Last Name10","description":"Random generated Last Name","example":"Davis","category":"person"},{"type":"domain","name":"Domain Name11","description":"Random generated WWW Domain Name","example":"google.com","category":"it"},{"type":"Gender","name":"Gender12","description":"Random generated Gender Type","example":"Female","category":"person"},{"type":"first_name","name":"First Name13","description":"Random generated First Name","example":"Jason","category":"address"},{"type":"last_name","name":"Last Name14","description":"Random generated Last Name","example":"Davis","category":"person"},{"type":"domain","name":"Domain Name15","description":"Random generated WWW Domain Name","example":"google.com","category":"it"},{"type":"Gender","name":"Gender16","description":"Random generated Gender Type","example":"Female","category":"person"}];

var categories = mock_data_types.reduce((categories, dataType) => {
    categories[dataType.category] = categories[dataType.category] || [];
    categories[dataType.category].push(dataType);
    return categories;
}, {});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(categories, null, '  ') + '</pre>');
```

Comment: An `if` statement might be more elegant, and would certainly cut down on the unnecessary assignment. https://jsfiddle.net/4b7e8gzp/

Comment: @Oka there are many ways to achieve the same result. Seems mostly personal preference

Answer (score 0):

If you are not adverse to using a library, I would tell you to get [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/).  Using the where function you could do something like below to accomplish your results.

```
_.where(mock_data_types, {'category': 'person'});
```

I would also like you can get more complex with the plucking of the data and add as many properties as you like such as:

```
_.where(mock_data_types, {'category': 'person', 'type': 'first_name'});
```

Comment: I'd suggest using [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy) instead

Comment: @Phil Thats a great suggestion, but I think he said he wanted an array filled with objects, not an object filled with arrays.

Comment: It would be an object, keyed by the categories, each with an array filled with objects